# create a new slave node in jenkins without restart

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I copied `/var/lib/jenkins/nodes/$node_name/config.xml` to new ***jenkins server*** `/var/lib/jenkins/nodes/$node_name/config.xml` (also created $node_name) directroy in new jenkins server

It doesn't appear in UI unless I restart the jenkins server. But If i create any new nodes from UI it doesn't require any restart.

I guess we can write some groovy script to do this, please provide any suggestions to fix this issue.

I tried `"Load config from disk"` from jenkins UI , but it refreshes only jobs and not nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create new slaves from the command line, try the [Jenkins CLI](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI) - specifically the create-node command.  You can get a CLI reference from the /cli page on your Jenkins master.

Comment: I copied slave xml from current production machine and gave that as a cli input as below and it worked , java -jar /jar/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://$Jenkins_IP:8080 create-node migration_test_node --username uname --password pass